# json API plugin not returning any post with get_category_posts

Tags: json, plugin-json-api

I am using the `json api` for the `api` calls in my WordPress site. When I tried

http://example.com/api/get_category_posts&slug=catname

Then the default post category news can not be obtained.

And The response is: `{"status":"error","error":"Not found."}`

Do anybody have idea, what's wrong with this?

Comment: Please post some complete code so we can debug it maybe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `post_type` to see if that fixes it?

I know documentation doesn't say it's required, but in the past I was only able to get it to work by passing the post type

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/